# Distinguish samename apps installed?

Tags: applications

I sometimes installed apps with the same name. Checking their info doesn't help me distinguish between them,because i think the only way is to find out the authors, and app info doesn't provide that. How can we distinguish samename apps installed? Can we fi d out their authors? Thanks!

Comment: How would you like to distinguish between them? I mean, is there a goal attached that I'm unable to see? E.g. in Lollipop, you can see package name (always distinguished) of apps in Settings -> Apps. In some custom launchers you can rename the apps. Besides, icons are usually enough to distinguish sometimes. See if [App Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.japanesecrackers.appbrowser) helps.

Comment: E.g., i have two apps called Messaging. One, only after i open it to find out, is from Freedompop, while i can't find out about the other